# Jackson XML + don't wrap value in tags

Tags: java, xml, jackson

Hi is it possible to change with Jackson (XML) the following

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<status id="1" count="5471">
  <status>Finished</status>
</status>
```

to this instead:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<status id="1" count="5471">Finished</status>
```

My code looks like this:

```
@JsonRootName("status")
public class StatusDto {

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private Long id;

  private String status;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private Integer count;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@JacksonXmlText`.

```
@JsonRootName("status")
class StatusDto {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private Long id;

    @JacksonXmlText
    private String status;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private Integer count;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, was searching this for over an hour. Thanks!